# VLC playlist, record where I left off

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

I created a playlist on VLC, the issue is that there is no way, that I can see, to record the current state.

So for example I have 20 videos on the playlist, I am playing video 12 and when I close VLC I was hoping that that information would be saved somewhere so that next time I open the playlist I would start at video 12 at the current time I stopped.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154020/

Maybe try this addon and see if the checkpoints help.

I use emby as a media server to watch tv shows and it has resume capabilities you can set up your videos like episodes in a tv show and it will treat it like one.

Kodi is pretty lightweight and the same can be accomplished by pointing it to your directory and turning on the option in settings.

VLC cant remember settings between sessions by default but it has the functionality to resume and make bookmarks if you leave it open.